# Node HTTP Server EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js

I'm currently writing an mocha test for my project.
The test should cover the output of an ajax request and therefore I created a simple HTTP-Server with node.

This is the current code:

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.write('test');
});

const port = 5555;

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log("Unhandled Exception, shutting down Server ...")
  server.close();
  console.log("Server closed!");
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  console.log("Termination called, shutting down Server ...");
  server.close();
  console.log("Server closed!");
  process.exit(1);
});

server.listen('success', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });
  res.write(JSON.stringify({
    success: true,
    message: "Form success!"
  }));
  res.close();
});

server.listen('fail', function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  });
  res.write(JSON.stringify({
    success: false,
    message: "Form fail!"
  }));
  res.close();
});

server.listen(port);
console.log("Server running on Port: " + port);
```

Now for some reason it always throws me an EADDRINUSE error even when the port isn't used. I killed all node/nodejs processes (there weren't any), searched for the program which is using the port (lsof -i tcp:5555) which didn't send any back and even restarted the machine without any difference.

This is the output of the Terminal:

```
Server running on Port: 5555
Unhandled Exception, shutting down Server ...
Server closed!
{ Error: listen EADDRINUSE success
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1249:19)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1382:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/dominik/Documents/workspace/jelly/test/test-server.js:23:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: 'success',
  port: -1 }
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I tried to search for solutions already of course, but all I find is kill the server with the same commands. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried running lsof as an admin user (`sudo lsof -i tcp:5555`) ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with  `server.listen('fail',...` and `server.listen('success'...` ?

Comment: it's the very first sentence. I try to test out the AJAX handling in my project and therefore need some dummy responses to test out the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the http module correctly. With the statement `server.listen('success',...)` you are [starting a UNIX socket server](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_path_callback) on the socket "success" which makes no sense.

Below is an example where the http server returns different responses based in the requested url. I recommend reading this [tutorial](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/).

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    });
    var responseBody = {};
    if (req.url === '/success') {
      responseBody = {
        success: true,
        message: "Form success!"
      };
    }
    if (req.url === '/fail') {
      responseBody = {
        success: false,
        message: "Form fail!"
      };
    }
    res.write(JSON.stringify(responseBody));
    res.end();
  });

const port = 5555;

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  console.log("Unhandled Exception, shutting down Server ...")
  server.close();
  console.log("Server closed!");
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
});

process.on('SIGTERM', function () {
  console.log("Termination called, shutting down Server ...");
  server.close();
  console.log("Server closed!");
  process.exit(1);
});


server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log("Server running on Port: " + port);
});
```

Test:

```
curl http://localhost:5555/success
curl http://localhost:5555/fail
```